# How to call user activity in code

Tags: swift, uikit, nswindowcontroller

I am trying to send an action to my custom activity in first responder from the toolbar. For a image button, I know that I can drag and drop to the first responder. But I wanted to have 3 button in segmented control. It seems that I can not set individual action of the segmented cell from storyboard.

So my next idea was send the action directly to Window controller, and from there, I could try to send it to my first responder's custom action. I tried the following code without any success.

```
@IBAction func visibilityChanged(_ sender: NSSegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegment {
    case 0:
        self.try(toPerform: Selector(("showStructure")), with: sender)
    case 1:
        self.try(toPerform: Selector(("showActivity")), with: sender)
    case 2:
        self.try(toPerform: Selector(("showOutput")), with: sender)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Was my approach wrong? If so, how should I do it? If not, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.try(toPerform: Selector(("showStructure")), with: sender)` sends `showStructure` to `self` which is the window controller.

Send the action to the first responder with `sendAction(_:to:from:)` of `NSApplication`.

```
NSApp.sendAction(#selector(showStructure(_:)), to: nil, from: sender)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have resolved it with below code. NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showStructure:")), to: nil, from: sender)